# HTTP POST Request Sometimes Can't Get Response (PHP and SIM800L)

Tags: php, firebase, arduino, http-post, sim800

I'm working on getting location from google geolocation api and sending this data to firebase. Theese two service using https ssl connections. And SIM800L very bad at ssl/tls connections. So I added my own server between SIM800L and internet. My server takes http request without ssl/tls from SIM800L and send them to they needs to go. A couple of lines PHP code doing this.

This method is working for me, I can take geolocation data and can send them to firebase. The problem is, sometimes request fails with using SIM800L. It's no problem with [postman](https://www.postman.com) or [reqbin](https://reqbin.com), it never fails. But with sim800l mostly 3 out of 5 requests fail. what causes this I don't know.

This is my PHP code handles requests:

```php
<?php
require 'firebaseLib.php';
// Tüm hataları göster
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// POST verilerini al
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');

// POST verilerini bir değişkene atama ve JSON verisi varsa decode et
$receivedData = json_decode($postData, true);

// Google Geolocation API bilgileri
$geolocation_hostname = "www.googleapis.com";
$geolocation_resource = "/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=****************************";
$geolocation_port = 443;

const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://*******************.firebasedatabase.app/';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = '****************************';
$DEFAULT_PATH = '/location_app'; // Firebase'deki ana yolunuzu düzenleyin

// Google Geolocation API'ye cURL ile POST isteği gönderme
$ch = curl_init("https://{$geolocation_hostname}{$geolocation_resource}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $geolocation_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($receivedData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // verbose çıktı için bu satırı ekleyin

// Güvenlik katmanlarını devre dışı bırakma
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

// API'den gelen cevabı al
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// verbose çıktıyı sayfaya yazdır
echo '<pre>';
echo "Verbose Çıktı:\n" . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) . $response;
echo '</pre>';

// İstek başarılı mı kontrol et
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Hata:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // API'den gelen veriyi decode et ve latitude, longitude değişkenlerine atayarak sakla
    $apiResponse = json_decode($response, true);
    
    if (isset($apiResponse['location']['lat']) && isset($apiResponse['location']['lng'])) {
        $latitude = $apiResponse['location']['lat'];
        $longitude = $apiResponse['location']['lng'];
        
        // Alınan latitude ve longitude değerlerini Firebase'e gönder
        

        

        $firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);

        $_devicestatus = array(
            'latitude' => $latitude,
            'longitude' => $longitude
        );

        $firebase->update($DEFAULT_PATH, $_devicestatus);

        echo "Firebase'e başarıyla gönderildi.<br>";
        echo "Latitude: {$latitude}<br>";
        echo "Longitude: {$longitude}<br>";
    } else {
        echo "API'den beklenen veri alınamadı.";
    }
}

// cURL bağlantısını kapat
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And this is my arduino code (sim800l):

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#if defined ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#elif defined ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
#else
#error Wrong platform
#endif

#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800


// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial
#define SerialAT Serial1


//#if !defined(TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER)
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 2048
//#endif
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon
#define MODEM_RST            5
#define MODEM_PWKEY          4
#define MODEM_POWER_ON       23
#define MODEM_TX             27
#define MODEM_RX             26


#define MAX_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT 5000
#define MAX_WIFI_SCAN 127

// Your GPRS credentials, if any
const char apn[]  = "internet";// CHANGES: Add your apn from the service provider of your simcard
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

// Server details

// CHANGES: Add the name of your website. NOTE: DONT put any preceeding headers like "https://.."
const char server[] = "********.com"; 

/* 
 *  The data that you want to send should be in this format
 *  /upload.php is the php file on the server and a=8 is data
 *  sent to it. 
 *  
 *  To record a datapoint, append the value at the end of the 
 *  character array resource
 *  
 *  if you want to send an array of data values, form the request as 
 *  a[]=1&a[]=2....
 *  
    */
    
char resource[] = "/upload.php"; 
const int  port = 80;
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>


#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
  #include <StreamDebugger.h>
  StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
  TinyGsm modem(debugger);
#else
  TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
#endif

TinyGsmClient gsm_modem(modem);
HttpClient    client(gsm_modem, server, port);
 
unsigned long lastUpdateTime = 0;
const unsigned long updateInterval = 1L * 1000L;

void setup() {
  // Set console baud rate
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  
  pinMode(MODEM_PWKEY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MODEM_RST, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MODEM_POWER_ON, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(MODEM_PWKEY, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MODEM_RST, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MODEM_POWER_ON, HIGH);

  SerialMon.println("Wait...");

  // Set GSM module baud rate
  SerialAT.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, MODEM_RX, MODEM_TX);
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.init();
  SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
   SerialMon.print(apn);
   if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
      SerialMon.println(" fail");
      delay(10000);
      return;
    }
   SerialMon.println(" success");

   if (modem.isGprsConnected()) {
      SerialMon.println("GPRS connected");
  }

  SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
  SerialMon.println(server);
  if (!client.connect(server, port)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
  
  
}


void loop() {
   // send HTTP request every one second
  if(millis() - lastUpdateTime >=  updateInterval) {
      httpPostRequest();
      lastUpdateTime = millis();
   } 
}


void httpPostRequest(){
   // Makes the HTTP POST request
  SerialMon.println("Performing HTTP POST request...");
  
  
  if (client.connect(server,port)) {
    
  // CHANGES: Add server name in place of XXXX
    client.beginRequest();
    String body = "{\"considerIP\":false,\"wifiAccessPoints\":" + getSurroundingWiFiJson() + "}";
    String request = "POST " + String(resource) +" HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request += "Host: " + String(server) + "\r\n";
    request += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
    request += "User-Agent: ESP32\r\n";
    request += "Content-Length:" + String(body.length()) + "\r\n";
    request += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    request += body;
    client.println(request);
    client.endRequest();

Serial.println("*****************************");
Serial.println(request);
Serial.println("------------------------------");

  
    
  uint32_t timeout = millis();
  
  while (client.connected() && millis() - timeout < 10000L) {
     // Print available data
     while (client.available()) {
         char c = client.read();
         SerialMon.print(c);
         timeout = millis();
     }
    } 
   }
  
  client.stop();
  Serial.println("Server Disconnected");
}

String getSurroundingWiFiJson()
{
    String wifiArray = "[";

    int8_t numWifi = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    if (numWifi > MAX_WIFI_SCAN)
    {
        numWifi = MAX_WIFI_SCAN;
    }

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numWifi; i++)
    {
        wifiArray += "{\"macAddress\":\"" + WiFi.BSSIDstr(i) + "\",";
        wifiArray += "\"signalStrength\":" + String(WiFi.RSSI(i)) + ",";
        wifiArray += "\"channel\":" + String(WiFi.channel(i)) + "}";
        if (i < (numWifi - 1))
        {
            wifiArray += ",\n";
        }
    }
    WiFi.scanDelete();
    wifiArray += "]";
    return wifiArray;
}
```

Fail is something like this:
[it fails here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyDLD.png)  and not takeing respons (also at the server side nothing happens when fail)

In console output is directly "server disconnect".

(As I said sometimes its working and giving proper response but not mostly)

I increased timeout but nothing changed. I guess server closing connections or refuse something sometimes. But I don't know why sometimes it's working and sometimes not.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain more about the failures.  Is there an error mess or something else that explains what went wrong?

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for your respond. I addded more detail and a picture. Actaully before this php code, my code included file_get_contents() function. It causing 403 error for sim800l (it wasn't a problem with requesting with reqbin or postman. after I heard this function have something like ssl verification required, I changed the code as in the post code and 403 error solved) I think maybe some kind of problem like this exist in my code but maybe I cant see it. I am new at php.